# Problems with nested for loops

Tags: javascript, json

I am having problems adding a property and value to an object based on a value in a for loop.  Here's my code.

```
"use strict";

var chirper = {};
chirper.tweetsArray = [];
chirper.tweets = [];
chirper.friends = [];
chirper.friendsByName = [];



chirper.masterAjax = function (url, method, success, error, data) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            if (success && typeof (success) == 'function') {
                success(this.response, this.status);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (error && typeof (error) == 'function') {
                error(this.response, this.status)
            }
        }
    };
    request.onerror = function () {
        if (error && typeof (error) == 'function') {
            error(this.response, this.status);
        }
    };

    if (data) {
        request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    else {
        request.send();
    }
    };
```

This is a function that I use over and over depending on where I need to get or post info to.

```
chirper.getAllFriends = function ()  {
    chirper.masterAjax('https://example-name.example.com/ccchirper/friends/.json', 'GET', function (response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response); for (var i in data) { chirper.friends.push(data[i]); chirper.friendsByName.push(data[i].userName)};
    }, function (response, status) {
        alert('Status: ' + status + '. Error message: ' + response);
    });
};




chirper.getAllTweets = function () {
    for (var i in chirper.friendsByName){
        chirper.masterAjax('https://' + chirper.friendsByName[i] + '.example.com/ccchirper/tweets/.json', 
            'GET', 
            function (response) {
                var data = JSON.parse(response); 
                for (var j in data) { data[j].name = chirper.friendsByName[i]; chirper.tweetsArray.push(data[j]);
                };
            }, 
            function (response, status) {
                alert('Status: ' + status + '. Error message: ' + response);
            });
    };

}
```

I have been calling these functions from the console to test them.

I first call `chirper.getAllFriends()` to populate `chirper.friendsByName`.  An example of what it returns would be `['andy','bob','john','tom']`

After it returns I call `chirper.getAllTweets()` to populate `chirper.tweetsArray`

Then I call `chirper.tweetsArray` and it returns an array of objects [obj,obj,obj]

each of these objects is

```
obj
    text: "blah blah blah'
    image:  "url.goes.here.com"
    time: 124223534346
    name: tom
```

each object has the correct properties and values but the name property always get the value of the last name in the `chirper.friendsByName` array.

What I want to have happen is all objects from 'andy' should get the name 'andy', all the ones from 'bob' should get the name 'bob' etc.

Comment: I don't understand how to use their solution to solve my problem.

Comment: You need to put a closure in your for loop, so that i doesn't loose its value.